# Querying a belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables, "tasks" and "courses". There is a one to many relationship setup (tasks belongTo a course, courses hasMany tasks). I am trying to filter my list of tasks, but am confused as to how to query based on a column in the courses table.

In the courses table I have a column called "college_name". I have a dropdown filter, and when I select a college name from that, I want to return all tasks that are linked to rows in the courses table that has the same 'college_name'.

So the query I am trying to build is something along the lines of "select all the tasks that belong to a course with the college_name of X (college name is taken from dropdown select input. In my controller I am getting the dropdown value like this:

```
$college = Input::get('colleges_filter');
```

...which returns the college name (e.g. "Oxford College"). I now need to take that add use it in the query, but everything I try errors. Can anyone help please?

Comment: College seems redundant, I would create a new Model called `Colleges`, then all is more easy with ids :)

Answer (score 0):

Well in Eloquent this would work like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Task extends Model {

    public function course() {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Course::class, 'foreign_key');
    }
}

class Course extends Model {

    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Task::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

And you use it like:

```
Course::query->where('bla', 'bla')->tasks;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your Course model add this relation.

```
class Course extends Model {

    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
    }
}
```

Get the list of task base on course select writes this below query into a controller.

```
$college = Input::get('colleges_filter');
$course = Course::where('college_name', $college)->with('tasks)->first();
```

You can access course list by

```
$course->tasks
```